# Using induction to prove a question based on Hermite polynomials

Tags: derivatives, induction, hermite-polynomials

I am practising for  a test that I have next week on proofs. I have tried to do this question using induction, but it is quite different to other induction questions I have done. Any guidance/walkthrough would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: You asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3900395/i-am-unsure-about-this-question-using-hermite-polynomials-and-satifying-recurren) before.  The same comment applies:  start by proving the base case $n=1$.  Then work the next couple of cases by hand to get the sense of how it works.

Comment: LOL. This exercise comes with the induction step almost in plain text. How much *more* guidance could one possibly need?!

Comment: thats the point of the question @ProfessorVector